# Call same promise within itself

Tags: javascript, promise

Still trying to wrap my head around promises and how they work. Im querying the Google webmaster API to return Search Analytics data. I've set up a promise which returns the data if i call it once however i need to call it again based on the result of the previous.

For example:

```
startRow = 0;
data = [];

Query(startRow).then((results) => {
  if (results != null) {
    data.push(results)
    startRow++;
    // RUN SAME QUERY AGAIN
  };
});
```

startRow needs to increase by 1 then call the same promise (with the updated startRow) if the promise returned data. Is this possible or am i looking at this totally the wrong way?

Comment: I would just create another method and call it within the method you have the original promise (e.g. anotherQuery()) I've been taught to look at code and break up big blocks into subroutines (different methods) that each do a specific thing. Makes it more readable

Comment: Make a function (you can't call a promise). Then just call that promise-returning function at the place where your comment says.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call the same Promise more than once, only create new ones.

```
startRow = 0;
data = [];

function startQuery() {
    // Generally a good idea to always return Promises,
    // so you can chain them if needed
    return Query(startRow).then(processResults);
}

function processResults(results) {
    if (results == null) return;

    data.push(results);
    startRow++;
    return startQuery();
};

startQuery();
```

Or, in a more compact way:

```
startRow = 0;
data = [];

function startQuery() {
    return Query(startRow).then((results) => {
        if (results == null) return;

        data.push(results);
        startRow++;
        return startQuery();
    });
}

startQuery();
```

Comment: Don't forget to `return` the respective promise (from *both* functions) so that you can chain onto it, and know when all queries are done

Comment: Well it's not needed for the scope of this question, but fair point and good practice nonetheless, editing answer to add

Comment: this works perfectly. exactly what i needed. thankyou! makes total sence now.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a function that recursively returns all of the results from a certain page onward, then call that with an initial page value of 0:

```
function queryPaged(pageNum, soFar) {
    return Query(pageNum).then(function (results) {
        return results
            ? queryPaged(pageNum + 1, soFar.concat(results))
            : soFar;
    });
}

queryPaged(0, []).then(function (allResults) {
    console.log(allResults);
});
```